# Russian analogue of "completely cleared computer game"

Tags: перевод, одним-словом, idioms

Sometimes computer game may contain main part and several extra things/possibilities for player. So there is a difference between "I've finished that game" and "I've completely cleared/beat that game". Second one implies that you have finished all extra quests, gathered all items etc (depends on game). I know 2 such expression:

1. Completely cleared/beat game. As explained above, to say this you should complete all quests, collect all items, get all gold medals etc.
2. 1CC (one-credit-clear). That means you have finished game without continuing at all (or using just one live).

In Russian "пройти игру" и "полностью пройти игру" still stands for simple completing of the game. Is there any short expression analogue for complete game clearing?

Answer (score 1):

There are several cases:

- "100% прохождение" for in-game messages and most of official translations
- "полное прохождение" for walkthrough articles

In all cases *complete* better to specify explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

no equal translation in official russian.
however it is possible to hear something like this:

-- Ты вчера играл в "game", как прошел ?
-- Вычистил все.

Comment: I would say "зачистил" - as in cleaned completely with an added military meaning of killed everyone.

Comment: If a game is based on FPS action only then it is may be.

Comment: Both phrases provided sounds like western spies in bad soviet movies - it's very unnatural Russian - it's not about using slang or something - it's just unnatural.

Comment: @Qwerty ну блин кто так про комьтерные игры говорит - я зачистил Kings Quest? Diablo? Doom?

Comment: я так говорю. "зачистил уровень"

Answer (score 0):

Закончил игр*ать* would mean finish the game (finished playing, to be precise)

Закончил игр*у* means cleared the game not necessarily beat the game; could be lost as well).

Comment: Закончил играть means stopped gaming, -1